# Filtering a FilteredList using Regex?

Tags: java, regex, javafx

I have a TextField that allows the user to search for an Employee from a Singleton database. Every employee has a first name and last name.

```
searchBar.textProperty().addListener(
            (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
               filteredList.setPredicate(arg0 -> {
                  String nameString = arg0.getFirst() + arg0.getLast();
                  nameString = nameString.toUpperCase();
                  if (arg0.getFirst().toLowerCase()
                        .contains(newValue.toLowerCase())
                        || arg0.getLast().toLowerCase()
                              .contains(newValue.toLowerCase()))
                     return true;
                  return false;
               });
            });
```

If I have a person named "John Smith", the filter will work fine if I search for:
"John"
"john"
"Smith"
"smith"
but NOT
"John Smith"
"Smith John"
"Smith, John"
How can I use my search query with regex correctly to find the Employee? A query of 5 words, for example, has 15 substrings that we can try to test for.

JACOB
J
A
C
O
B
JA
AC
CO
OB
JAC
COB
JACO
ACOB

It would be far too expensive to search for every possible match this way. What is the most efficient way to do it? I want to be able to find John Smith with "Johnsmith" or "Smithjo" or something of the sort.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex could be like ".*(?:John|Smith).*"
I will search for any sentence which contains the word "John" or the word "Smith".
Is it what you want?
Niko